# Android - TabHost inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-xml

I'm writing an app that implements nested tabs. Because two sets of tabs occupy quite a bit of space and generally because the nature of the content I would like to place the whole inner TabHost into a scrollable structure. I can make tabcontent of the outer activity FrameLayout, LinearLayout, even ViewFlipper; when I try to make it ScrollView, the program crashes.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

So apparently TabHost likes to live inside non-scrollable frames. Is there any way to go around this without creating a whole lot of a mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I figured it out on my own. The solution is to wrap the second TabHost inside a ScrollView within its own XML file. That works just fine.

Outer:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Inner:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabHost 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>

</ScrollView>
```